# Cannot import python class from another folder

Tags: python

I have created 2 classes
`Connections.py` and `LogObserver.py`

I am trying to import Connections.py in LogObserver.py but python keep throwing an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connections'
```

The way i am importing it is

```
from connections.Connections import Connections


class LogObserver:
```

The file structure is
[image]

Comment: Do you use a `main.py` or equivalent to run the whole project? If so, is the main file being run from the correct working directory? I.e. is `python main.py` command entered in the same directory where connections and queries folders are?

Comment: I am trying to run only the LogObserver class

Comment: Since it seems like you're using VSCode, make sure the path VSCode is running `LogObserver.py` from is in whatever folder the `connections` and `queries` folders are. You can change the working directory manually in VSCode terminal/console. Python tries to import local modules from the current working directory, meaning from the subfolders. It can not go up/back from the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your Class name in Connections file is called Connections then you can try following:

```
from connections import Connections
c = Connections.Connections()
```

Or:

```
import connections.Connections as myModule
c = myModule.Connections()
```

make sure when you import that you do following:

```
from <folder>.<filename> import <class_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your file structure.
Try keeping connections folder inside queries folder OR specify the file path for connections.py correctly.

Hope it resolves the issue.